# Header file not found in Bridging Header after upgrade to XCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header

I have some project which I wrote using XCode 6 with iOS deployment target and which was working fine on iOS 8.

Recently I upgraded XCode to 7.0.1 (7A1001) and now I have to make some changes in mentioned project. I can't event build it.

I'm using CocoaPods and I have `UIColor+BFPaperColors` imported : `pod 'UIColor+BFPaperColors', '~> 1.3.1'`.

XCode is telling me that he can't find `UIColor+BFPaperColors.h` file. It's strange because I have this file in my project (Pods project in Workspace) and it was working fine with XCode 6.

[image: Error in XCode 7]

What I already tried to do (but with no result) :

1. Convert project to latest Swift syntax (Edit -> Convert -> To latest Swift syntax...).
2. Set `Allow non-modular includes in Framework Modules` to YES.
3. Did `pod update` and `pod install`.

PS. Here is my [Podfile](http://pastebin.com/fxKBCxRh).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Related image]

do you use the Build Setting to set bridging header? maybe this picture will
help you

Comment: Yes, bridging header is set in Build Settings.

Comment: use #import ""   instead of import <>  try again